# How do I pass an HTML `data-` string attribute into a SCSS mixin via attr()?

Tags: html, css, sass, mixins, scss-mixins

I am trying to set up a color scheme in SCSS where I can have the following HTML:

```html
<div class="swatch" data-bg="green">...</div>
```

I have a SCSS mixin defined as such:

```
@function color($key: 'black') {
  @return map-get($colors, $key);
}
```

So, if I pass it `background-color: color('green')`, it will look at the `$colors: ( ... )` map, see `'green': #009900,` and return `background-color: #009900;` as the CSS.

The problem comes when I try to pass the `data-bg` attribute value into the `color()` SCSS mixin, like so:

```
.swatch[data-bg] {
  background-color: color(attr(data-bg));
}
```

This doesn't work. I would *expect* it to parse the value as such:

`color(attr(data-bg))` → `color('green')` → `#009900`

However, SCSS won't even render that `background-color` line in the CSS at all.

I have a Codepen where you can see what I'm trying to go for. It's the "Brown" color swatch here: https://codepen.io/rbrum/pen/axZLxw

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: SASS is precompiled so you can't use runtime variables.

Comment: You can still use `attr()`, you'll just have to omit the SASS-specific `color()` and make sure that the contents of the attribute are valid color notations in CSS.

Comment: Since that is true, @JamesCoyle, I guess all I can hope for is a SASS function/mixin that takes in a string, and call it with each color name. E.g. `@include generate-bg-color('brown');`, etc.

Comment: Actually, I've written an `@each` loop that iterates through each color in the map, then generates the background colors that way. This way, I can just have `class="swatch green"`, and in my SASS I can apply styling to each color class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone else who happens across this question,  here is how I ended up resolving my issue.

Instead of relying on `data-` attributes, I just relied on class names instead. Whenever I want an element with a certain background color, for instance, I use a class name like `.bg-amber` or `.bg-purple`. My colors are defined as such:

```
$colors: (
  'black': #000000,
  'white': #FFFFFF,
  // ...
  'amber': #FFBF00,
  'purple': #800080,
  // ...
);
```

To make it easier to access a color, I have defined a function that calls any color by name:

```
@function c($key: 'black') {
  @return map-get($colors, $key);
}
```

I then define a mixin that, given a color name, will apply it as the background color. I can also pass it a prefix that is used in the CSS attribute.

```
@mixin bg($color-name, $prefix: '') {
  .#{$prefix}#{$color-name} {
    background-color: c($color-name);
  }
}
```

If I wanted to use it in a one-off situation, I would use it like so:

```
@include bg('amber', 'bg-');
```

...which would generate the following:

```css
.bg-amber {
  background-color: #FFBF00;
}
```

Finally, I use an `@each` loop to do this for all of my colors:

```
@each $color-name, $color-val in $colors {
  @include bg($color-name, 'bg-');
}
```

---

I can also define a "foreground" version:

```
@mixin fg($color-name, $prefix: '') {
  .#{$prefix}#{$color-name} {
    color: c($color-name);
  }
}
```

And then I can use it in the `@each` loop right below the `bg()` usage:

```
@each $color-name, $color-val in $colors {
  @include bg($color-name, 'bg-');
  @include fg($color-name, 'txt-');
}
```

It can also be extended for things like border colors, box shadows, and more.